# Stanford Dependency Parser Jython

Tags: dependencies, nlp, jython

I am using the code from 
http://blog.gnucom.cc/2010/using-the-stanford-parser-with-jython/ 
to generate the dependency parse.

```jython
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/jar/stanford-parser-2008-10-26.jar')

from java.io import CharArrayReader
from edu.stanford.nlp import *

lp = parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser('/path/to/englishPCFG.ser.gz')
tlp = trees.PennTreebankLanguagePack()
lp.setOptionFlags(["-maxLength", "80", "-retainTmpSubcategories"])

sentence = 'One of my favorite features of functional programming \
languages is that you can treat functions like values.'

toke = tlp.getTokenizerFactory().getTokenizer(CharArrayReader(sentence));
wordlist = toke.tokenize()

if (lp.parse(wordlist)):
    parse = lp.getBestParse()

gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory()
gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse)
tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCollapsed()

print parse.toString() 
print tdl
```

It gives a list which contains tuples of the type:

```
<type 'edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TypedDependency'>
```

How can I access the individual tuples to use the dependency parse?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the *TypedDependency* class is available at http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TypedDependency.html. I couldn't get the model to load with my version of Java (5 is required, but I have 7).

This should give you a start though:

```
for type_dep in tdl:
    print "Governor word:", type_dep.gov().toString() # .gov() is an IndexedWord
    print "Dependent word:", type_dep.dep().toString() # .dep() is an IndexedWord
    print "Relation:", type_dep.reln().toString() # .reln() is a GrammaticalRelation
    print
```